# Default Wordpress WP Editor removing style tags and html tag

Tags: plugins, wp-admin

I am working inside the WP Admin area and there is a textarea that is using the default WP Editor, **not** TinyMCE.  The WP Editor is removing the `<style>` tag and also other HTML tags.  I am calling it WP Editor, but maybe it's official know as something different?  It's the editor with the two tabs in the right corner (Visual,Text)

Is there a way to prevent this Editor from removing all HTML tags?

The content I am adding in the WP Editor is being used in outgoing emails so it's really a full HTML document which is why I am trying to preserve the formatting and html tags.

I notice when I switch from the "Text" tab to the "Visual" tab many HTML tags are stripped.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a user capability called [`unfiltered_html`](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#unfiltered_html). Any user with the `unfiltered_html` capability can post any HTML they want, including `<script>` tags.

[Due to security concerns, the `unfiltered_html` capability is—by default—only granted to Administrators (in WordPress Multisite, it's only granted to Super Administrators).](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#additional-admin-capabilities)

If you need to add the `unfiltered_html` capability to a non-(Super-)Admin user, you can use [`WP_User::add_cap()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/add_cap/) to add it to a user:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_393657_grant_user_unfiltered_html' );
function wpse_393657_grant_user_unfiltered_html() {
    $user = get_user_by( 'login', 'my_username' );
    if ( ! user_can( $user, 'unfiltered_html' ) ) {
        $user->add_cap( 'unfiltered_html', true );
    }
}
```

...or [`WP_Role::add_cap()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_role/add_cap/) to add it to a Role (eg, Editor).

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_393657_grant_role_unfiltered_html' );
function wpse_393657_grant_role_unfiltered_html() {
    $role = get_role( 'editor' );
    if ( ! $role->has_cap( 'unfiltered_html' ) ) {
        $role->add_cap( 'unfiltered_html', true );
    }
}
```

(These code snippets are untested, and are meant to provide a starting point for you.)

Note that the capability assignments are permanent (ie, written to the database), and that the user or role will retain the `unfiltered_html` capability until/unless you revoke it.

Comment: The "unfiltered html" capability is by default only granted to admins?  I am currently an admin and this is a single site (not multisite) and it is stripping out the HTML tags.  Does this need to be turned on explicitly @pat-j?

Comment: Hmm, good question. I thought Admins were granted `unfiltered_html`. Can you [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/393657/edit), please, to include the code that generates your WP Editor in the backend? (If it's a 3rd-party plugin, you might need to ask their support team for assistance with this.)